# CSS transform moves click handler?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I tend to use the following SCSS `@mixin` for an animation effect to let users know what is interactive on my projects.

```
@mixin clickAnimation($opacity: 0.5, $distance: -1px, $time: 75ms) {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: $time ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    transform: translateY($distance);
    opacity: $opacity;
  }
  &:active {
    transform: translateY(2px);
  }
}
```

I'll tend to use it across the site like this:

```
a:not(.disabled) {
  @include clickAnimation();
}
```

Recently I've noticed a quirky issue with this.

If the user hovers the `<a>` element on the bottom pixel of the `<a>`, the `<a>` will transform up to `-1px`. When the user clicks the `<a>`, the `:active` css state will perform (in this case, translating down to `2px`), but the click action will not register. So no click handlers will fire, and no links will cause redirects.

Has anyone had this issue before and know what I could do to fix it?

As requested, here is a fiddle which demonstrates the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/bf9yk0tn/

Comment: Please add a snippet so we can see the problem.

Comment: Hi Arkellys, sure thing. Please see the fiddle below. If you click the bottom pixel of the link, nothing happens.

https://jsfiddle.net/bf9yk0tn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the DOM looses track of the element since its moving from its original position and there's nothing at the time click event occurs (somehow it manages the hover though).

You can go for a workaround like this to fill the void but Im not sure if its the best solution.

```
a:hover::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here's the update [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KasunWijeratne/6y8xow2p/3/)

Comment: Thanks Kassa, yeah very strange behavior but this works! Which is kind of funny imo,